# Can't move text within button

Tags: html, css, button

I've been making a button of sorts.

However, I've come into a spot of trouble.

When making it smaller it pushes the text out of the box, and I can't seem to to put it back in.

Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/ByxRh/1/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: how big do you need it to be? you want it fixed or changing size on content?

Comment: The line-height on `p.speech` is causing the vertical spacing.

Comment: and you should add a position:relative;z-index:1; on the span so that the text won't be hidden

Comment: @Onheiron I'd like it to sit within. Font size is 20px at the moment. Wouldn't mind keeping it that size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the line-height was set to twice the height of the `p`.

```
p.speech {
     height:50px;
     line-height:100px;
}
```

If you simply set the line-height of the `p` to exactly the height that you want the `p` to appear, and don't give it any explicit height, it should look fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ByxRh/16/

```
p.speech {
     line-height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByxRh/13/)

here is an updated version of your code. Just try messing around with height, font size etc until you get it how you want.